# Cómo incluir alternativas opcionales de texto en una expresión regular

Tags: javascript, json, regex

Estoy ayudándome de un JSON para validar datos de una serie de facturas. Lo primero, he quitado todos los espacios a los datos, y después valido los campos según la definición que se encuentra en un JSON. Me ha servido perfectamente, pero ahora me encuentro con un pequeño problemilla:

Si quería validar el texto:

> Total electricidad 54,60€

Lo hacía de esta manera:

```
"regexp": {
          "productType": "Electricidad",
          "electricityTotal": "Totalelectricidad([\\d\\,\\.]+)€"
}
```

Pero quiero validar facturas en euskera, catalán...etc. No sé cómo hacer que filtre el siguiente texto:

> Argindarra guztira / Total electricidad 54,60€

**Mi problema es cómo hacer que incluya la barra "/" y la tome como parte del string, ya que es lo único que cambia en la expresión.**

Quiero que se reconozca el caracter `"/"` como parte del string, por ejemplo:

```
"regexp": {
          "productType": "Electricidad",
          "electricityTotal": "Argindarraguztira/Totalelectricidad([\\d\\,\\.]+)€"
}
```

En este caso me da error, porque algo me falta incluir a la expresión para que admita la "/".

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta. Si consideramos los espacios que faltan en tu expresión, `Total electricidad [\d.,]+€` coincide con ambos textos. ¿Cuál es el problema?

Comment: Me gustaría que sea más específico y lea "Argindarra guztira / Total electricidad", no solo "Total electricidad". Y no encuentro la forma de que se incluya la "/" al string

Comment: No debería darte ningún error la barra. Podés ver cómo funciona en https://jsfiddle.net/6crgesxt/. ¿Será algún problema con otra parte del código?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu expresion puede funcionar pero puede dar fallos.

Por ejemplo, con tu parte de `[\\d\\,\\.]+` le estas diciendo que coja 1 o más de esos elementos pero no todas las combinaciones son válidas.

Por eso pondría:

```
\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?€
```

que busca numeros seguidos de la posiblidad de punto/coma y más numeros.

Ej:

- Válidos: `5555€`, `55.55€`, `5,55555€`
- Inválidos: `55,.55€`, `55,€`, `.55€`

---

Para que acepte la posibilidad de tener otro idioma delante de "Total electricidad" puedes poner un grupo opcional `(?:Argindarra guztira \/ )?` quedando todo:

```
^(?:Argindarra guztira \/ )?Total electricidad \d+(?:[,.]\d+)?€$
```

Si quisieras añadir otros idomas puedes poner más usando el operador  `"|"`(or) y los demás idiomas.

```
(?:(?:Argindarra guztira|Total electricitat) \/ )?
```

---

```js
comprobar();

function comprobar() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("prueba");
  var p = document.getElementById("resultado");
  var pattern = /^(?:(?:Argindarra guztira|Total electricitat) \/ )?Total electricidad \d+(?:[,.]\d+)?€$/;

  if (pattern.test(elem.value.trim()) || elem.value.trim() == "") {

    p.innerHTML = "ok";

  } else {

    p.innerHTML = "nok";

  }
}

$('input').bind('input propertychange', function() {
  comprobar();
});
```

```css
input{

   width:100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="prueba" value="Argindarra guztira / Total electricidad 555,5€">

<p id="resultado"></p>
```

Comment: Perfecto, me puede valer y he cambiado lo que me dijiste porque tienes razón. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda y tu tiempo!! :)

Comment: De nada, @norak. Un saludo